# Posts with less than 4 close votes are displayed in close review page

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, review, vote-to-close

I have just read [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/223497/205508) about displaying only the questions with at least 4 close votes:

> Now, **only questions with at least 4 votes/flags are listed** in the close review queue. If you're thinking, "that's crazy!" THEN YOU'RE RIGHT! This dramatically reduces the utility of the queue. But, we've had one or two complaints about the size of the backlog, so it's time we took care of it.

I wanted to see the changes, and yeah, there are only 11.6k posts. I started to review them and I opened one to see how many close votes it has. It had 3 close votes. I guessed I was a temp problem.

Trying to reproduce the problem I opened another one. Randomly I will take the second one that appeared in the queue and has 1 close vote.

> [image]
>   [Link to the close vote review page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/3893878)

And here the vote count:

> [image]
>   [Link to question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21343017/1420197)

Aren't they completely burned down? `:-)`

Comment: This is __by-design__.   [To quote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223497/lets-burn-down-the-close-queue#comment728346_223497) @Shog9: `some will have a combination of flags and votes, others will have a combination of flags/votes and Do Not Close reviews`.

Comment: @devnull Define *Do not close review*. Is this same with *Leave open*? If yes, I already tried if clicking *Leave open* modifies the close vote count and it **doesn't**.

Comment: Well it doesn't change the close vote count because it's not a close vote. It changes the review count for that question though. Either way you can't see the flag count so you wouldn't know if it's working or not.